# Check if mouse buttons are swapped or not in C++

Tags: c++, winapi, click, mouseevent

I want to send some mouse click messages to a specified window of another program. I currently use `WM_LBUTTONUP` and `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` messages whose works fine.

These messages performs exactly same way regardless of a user's mouse button settings. Oppose from it, I want to know if user has swapped mouse buttons from mouse settings control panel.

I researched and found [**`SwapMouseButton`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646264(v=vs.85).aspx) function, it works fine but I don't want to swap mouse buttons actually and I just want to know whether it is previously swapped or not.

From MSDN:

> If the meaning of the mouse buttons was reversed previously, before the function was called, the return value is nonzero.

I can get the information I want this way, but it also restores them to original state of mouse buttons. I only want to check and not to restore to original state.

I currently call this function like:

```
SwapMouseButton(FALSE);
```

I like to know any other alternative way (something like `SystemParametersInfo`) to only check *(not to also restore)* whether mouse buttons has previously swapped by user.

Basically, what I want to do is simulate a primary mouse button click and a secondary mouse button click according to user's mouse button meanings.

For example, when I simulate a primary mouse button click, and if user has swapped the mouse buttons, right mouse click should simulate, otherwise left, as usual. There are no messages exist called `WM_PRIMARY...` and `WM_SECONDARY...` for me to do what I want.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have asked the wrong question, and now need help with the wrong solution. [You can’t simulate keyboard input with PostMessage](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050530-11/?p=35513) (the same underlying principles apply to mouse input). The question you should have asked instead: *"How do I automate a UI?"* The answer to that question is: *"Use [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx)."* One advantage of this is, that you do not need to know the user's local mouse button settings.

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks! I will remove `PostMessage`. The link you provided is very useful. :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [GetSystemMetrics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724385(v=vs.85).aspx) with `SM_SWAPBUTTON` parameter value.

> SM_SWAPBUTTON 23
>
> Nonzero if the meanings of the left and right mouse
>   buttons are swapped; otherwise, 0.